# How to keep a captured group only in Python regex?

Tags: python, regex

Please accept my apology if this is a dumb question.

I want to make a regex expression that can make the two following changes in Python.

1. `$12345.67890` to `12345.67`
2. `$12345` to `12345`

What would be an appropriate regex expression to make both changes?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in notepad++ style i would do something like 
find        `\$(\d+\.)(\d\d)\d+`
Replace     `\1\2`

hope that helps

Comment: Thank you. So calling subgroup is simply \#.

Comment: that is correct  @S.J. if it worked for you please accept the answer thanks

Answer (score 2):

We can try using `re.sub` here:

```
inp = "Here is a value $12345.67890 for replacement."
out = re.sub(r'\$(\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)\d*\b', '\\1', inp)
print(out)
```

This prints:

```
Here is a value 12345.67 for replacement.
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```
\$                  match $
(                   capture what follows
    \d+             match one or more whole number digits
    (?:\.\d{1,2})?  then match an optional decimal component, with up to 2 digits
)                   close capture group (the output number you want)
\d*                 consume any remaining decimal digits, to remove them
\b                  until hitting a word boundary
```

Comment: Thank you. I just have a quick question. What is the function of the first '?' sign in '(?:\.\d{1,2})?' expression?

Comment: @S.J. The `?:` inside the capture group tells Python to turn off, or _ignore_, that capture group.  In this case, we are only using `(...)` because we want to make the entire decimal component optional.  But, we aren't interested in actually capturing it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment again. I just have a quick question. It turns out that I have to use double backslash (i.e. \\1) as you answered above to reference the subgroup in Python. However, some other have answered with single backslash (i.e. \1) and I need to use single backslash on https://regex101.com/ to reference the subgroup. Why is there this difference?

Comment: In Python, `\1` is a control character.  In order to have literal `\1`, you need to escape the backslash once, i.e. use `\\1`.  It means the same thing as in your demo.